# CSS3 animation does not start in Opera if element initially had display: none

Tags: javascript, html, css, opera, css-animations

I'm trying to show infinitely rotating image after some event in js.
Works perfectly in Chrome 26, Firefox 19, but fails in Opera 12 (latest).

I use initial image with style="display: none" like this:

```
<img src="http://example.com/img.png" id="test" style="display: none">
```

Then I show the image (remove display: none):

```
$('#test').show();
```

Expected behavior: see rotating image. Rotation does not happen in Opera.
Is this an Opera bug? I know I can start animation by applying it with class after image is shown, but I want to figure out how to trigger it when image has animation set initially.
Animation works fine when the initial image is shown (display: block).

Here is jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/vdJLL/

CSS which I use for rotation:

```
#test {
  -webkit-animation: rotate 5s linear 0s infinite normal;
  -moz-animation: rotate 5s linear 0s infinite normal;
  -o-animation: rotate 5s linear 0s infinite normal;
  -ms-animation: rotate 5s linear 0s infinite normal;
  animation: rotate 5s linear 0s infinite normal;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to { 
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to { 
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to { 
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to { 
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: I would worry about it unless you have a large amount of Opera user and will be deploying very soon. Opera will be moving to [Web-Kit/Blink](http://thenextweb.com/insider/2013/04/04/opera-confirms-it-will-follow-google-and-ditch-webkit-for-blink-as-part-of-its-commitment-to-chromium/) soon.

Answer (score 1):

I've just ran into the similar problem - I've been trying to js display:none other div (that wasn't even affecting the animation) and got on Opera animation freezed (which, what's even more funny, could be unfreezed by entering dragonfly and re-enabling animation part of style) - so it sounds indeed like an Opera bug.

Anyways, I just learned a workaround - instead of `display:none`, it'll work with

`visibility:hidden; height: 0px;`

See also your jsfiddle updated http://jsfiddle.net/vdJLL/3/